# Comparison of solutions of Hamilton Jacobi Equationfor different initial value

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, hamilton-jacobi-equation

Let $u_i$ for 
$i=1,2$ be the solutions of Hamilton Jacobi equation

$u_t+f(u_x)=0  ;  (x,t) \in R\times (0,\infty)$

$u(x,0)=g_i(x)$  ; $x \in R$ $i=1,2$

(which are obtained by Hopf-Lax formula)

Where $g_i \in L^ \infty $ for $i=1,2$

if $g_1 \leq g_2$ how to show $u_1 \leq u_2$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: write explicitly the two solutions with the Hopf-Lax formula, and compare the arguments of the two "min".

Comment: oh thanks!! i got it..